# Wireless chargers in series?

Tags: battery-charging, wireless, buck, 12v, wireless-charging

I'm a complete amateur at electrical stuff, although I can solder and make some basic electronics with Arduino.

I'd like to wirelessly charge a battery in the rotating part of an astronomy dome. The battery is for lights and eventually a motor to open/close the dome hatch. I know about slip rings, but I'm wondering about wireless because, well, it would be cool.

So could I wire up ten 5 V 1 A Qi wireless chargers to get 50 V and then step down to 12 V to charge a 12 V battery at maybe 10 amps? When the dome is "parked", the chargers would line up and provide power. I would have to find a battery charger that takes DC instead of AC but those exist, no?

If this idea is terrible, does anyone have other ideas?

Comment: by the way, unit symbol of Volt is capital "V", not small "v". Unit symbol of Ampere is capital "A" not "amp". Did you perhaps mean to say "50V 1A" instead of "5V 1A" in your third paragraph, first sentence?

Comment: Even if that is the case, your calculation doesn't work out: If you put in 50V, 1A (= 50VA = 50W) , you can't step down to 12 V, 10 A (=120V), because that would require a perpetuum mobile

Comment: And: why do you need a battery when you could deliver the power when you need it, wirelessly?

Comment: qi chargers have to be thin, this is does not help you in this case. There are actual rotating transformers, they don't have to be thin and are possibly much more efficient. They might be a pain to source though. Just a thought.

Comment: Your idea of wireless charging will be a waste of electric energy.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but here are some ideas to make it work:

1. 10A charge is a lot. You probably don't want to play with over 120W (that is, 12V times 10A into the battery is a 120 watt charge) if your electronics experience is limited to Arduino stuff. Things will get hot. There will be sparks. Cables have to be big. Stuff will fail. 2A is a good place to start your design at - it's not an unusual basic 12V charger rate, so just do your calcs to ensure the charge time is adequate. 2A @ 15V (which is a safe estimate of the charge voltage of a 12V battery) is 30W, so 8 of the 5W qi chargers should get you over the line.
2. As @alex.forencich says, don't series them all. Make two sets of 4 in series and put the two sets in parallel. That'll give you 20V @ 2A. That's plenty of voltage headroom to drive a charger.
3. Have you considered replacing the wireless charges with contact pins or brushes? Since the wireless chargers will only work when the dome is parked, you could do the same with contact pins or brushes that make contact in the parked position. Much, much higher efficiency and much simpler, but at the loss of some coolness factor. I think you'll have a lot of trouble getting the chargers to align - they're designed to come close together and then magnetically snap into perfect alignment. Works fine when you have one attached to something light. But is not going to work so well if you have to align several of them, all rigidly fixed in space.
4. A charger that takes DC is not a problem. Even the chargers that take AC just convert to DC internally before supplying the actual charger. Finding one that meets your specs is always a mission, but technically speaking it's not a problem.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your info, ideas, corrections! I'm going to look into the contact pins/brushes idea a little more. One issue would be that there's a potential for snow to blow through the gap between the moving & fixed parts. It doesn't happen often, but I'd want to make sure moisture doesn't meet any contacts.

Comment: @barnett If the sliding contacts enter the contact area through brushes (as used for draught excluders on doors) then a lot of snow could be wiped off. Also, WD40.

Answer (score 0):

It actually doesn't sound like that bad of an idea.  It would probably work just dandy.  However, 10 of those in series would give you 50 volts at 1 amp, which is 50 watts.  If you use a switching converter to get that down to 12 volts, you can't draw more than about 4 amps.  However, I would not recommend putting them all in series; switching converters work better the less they have to change the voltage.  So two parallel strings of 5 in series would be better, producing 25 volts at 2 amps.

It's still not a bad idea to look in to slip rings of some sort, though.  It's entirely possible that you could build your own slip rings fairly economically from a couple of lengths of thin copper tubing or something similar and avoid not only the wireless chargers but also the battery.